# Capitalize each word in a string, how does this code check the previous space

Tags: java, if-statement, whitespace, capitalize, chararray

I recently came across this solution to writing a program that capitalizes each word in a string and I'm trying really hard to understand it, but I can't get over one hurdle.

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create a string
        String message = "everyone loves java";

        // stores each characters to a char array
        char[] charArray = message.toCharArray();
        boolean foundSpace = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {

            // if the array element is a letter
            if(Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {

                // check space is present before the letter
                if(foundSpace) {

                    // change the letter into uppercase
                    charArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[i]);
                    foundSpace = false;
                }
            }

            else {
                // if the new character is not character
                foundSpace = true;
            }
        }

        // convert the char array to the string
        message = String.valueOf(charArray);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
    }
```

I understand everything in this code except for how it checks if the previous character was a space. The comment says it does this with the `if(foundSpace)` statement, but I don't see any reason why that would work since it's never specified that it's looking for a space. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Edit: Thanks for everyone’s answers, I think I finally get it now!

Comment: The code, as written, defines "space" as "anything that isn't a letter". So it will consider `1`, `$`, and `"` spaces, for instance.

Comment: It would be clearer if the `else` was deleted and replaced with `foundSpace = !Character.isLetter(charArray[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code inside the loop, stripped down a bit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
  if(Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {
    // check space is present before the letter
    if(foundSpace) {
      // Some code.
      foundSpace = false;
    }

    // Here, foundSpace is false.

  } else {
    foundSpace = true;
  }
}
```

The code doesn't care about what your variables or methods are called: it's checking if the character meets some criterion (`Character.isLetter`), and afterwards it has recorded whether or not the character met that criterion (in `foundSpace`).

This means that `foundSpace` contains whether the *previous* character met that criterion, and allows you to decide to do something on the *current* character based on what the previous one was: in your case, uppercase that character if the previous character *didn't* meet the criterion.

`foundSpace` is initially set to `true`, which means that the loop treats a string which starts with a letter as if there was a space before it, and so that will be capitalized.

Really, there is just a mismatch between the criterion used, and the name of the variable:

- If the criterion should be "is it whitespace", use `Character.isWhitespace` as your criterion, and keep the flag name as `foundSpace`;
- If the criterion really is "is it a letter", use `Character.isLetter` as your criterion, and name the flag `foundLetter` (and invert its sense, so check `if (!foundLetter)` etc, because it's easier to deal with "positive" checks (`if (foundLetter)`) rather than "negative" checks (`if (!foundLetter)`)).

Comment: This helped a lot, I think it finally clicked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

foundSpace is only set to false if the condition:

```
    (Character.isLetter(charArray[i]))
```

is triggered.

If the condition is not triggered, aka if the character is not a letter, then foundSpace will be set to True.

This means that anything that is not a letter will set foundSpace equal to true.
As Silvio pointed out, this includes other non space characters such as 1, $, and ".

It would be better instead of checking if the character is a letter, to instead check to see if charArray[i] is equal to a space.

Like so:

```
    boolean foundSpace = Character.isWhitespace(charArray[i])
```

More info about the Character class can be found below:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/character-equals-method-in-java-with-examples/

The code you've shown could have some undesirable side effects - especially if foundSpace is relied upon later on - because it could potentially lead you to believe that a space exists in a word, when it's not a space at all but rather a character that isn't a letter like "$".

In the context of your entire program, this looks like:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create a string
    String message = "everyone loves java";

    // stores each characters to a char array
    char[] charArray = message.toCharArray();
    boolean foundSpace = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        if(Character.isWhitespace(charArray[i])){
            foundSpace = true;
        }
        else{
            foundSpace = false;
        }
        // if the array element is a letter
        if(Character.isLetter(charArray[i])) {
            // check space is present before the letter
            if(foundSpace) {

                // change the letter into uppercase
                charArray[i] = Character.toUpperCase(charArray[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            // if the new character is not character
            // delete this condition if you don't plan to use it
        }
    }

    // convert the char array to the string
    message = String.valueOf(charArray);
    System.out.println("Message: " + message);
}
```

Some edits made to the code to fix compilation errors, thanks to those in the comments for your suggestions.

Comment: `charArray[i].equals(new Character(' '))` doesn't compile because `charArray[i]` is a `char`, not a `Character`. (If it were a `Character`, you could use `characterArray[i].equals(' ')`, and allow autoboxing to do its thing, which is more efficient than allocating a new `Character` each time). `charArray[i] == ' '` would work; but this only matches one kind of space. A more general solution would be to use `Character.isWhitespace(charArray[i])`.

Comment: You mean it is only set to *false* under that condition.

Comment: ah yes, thanks, appreciate it

Comment: Also, think about `if (Character.isLetter(...)) { if (foundSpace)`: in what circumstance would `foundSpace` be `true`, given the preceding assignment if it's equal/not equal to space. I don't think OP needed the code rewriting to do something different, just explaining.